# react native gesture handler is not working with modal in Android

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

I am having an issue in using `PanGestureHandler` from `react-native-gesture-handler` with `Modal`. This is perfectly working in `iOS` but not in `android`. And Moreover when I changed `Modal` in to `View` component it is working in `Android` as well. Please any one can suggest me a solution for this problem.

```
class Circle extends Component {
  _touchX = new Animated.Value(windowWidth / 2 - circleRadius);
  _onPanGestureEvent = Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { x: this._touchX } }], { useNativeDriver: true });
  render() {
    return (
      <Modal
        isVisible={true}
      >
        <PanGestureHandler
          onGestureEvent={this._onPanGestureEvent}>
          <Animated.View style={{
            height: 150,
            justifyContent: 'center',
          }}>
            <Animated.View
              style={[{
                backgroundColor: '#42a5f5', borderRadius: circleRadius, height: circleRadius * 2, width: circleRadius * 2,
              }, {
                transform: [{ translateX: Animated.add(this._touchX, new Animated.Value(-circleRadius)) }]
              }]}
            />
          </Animated.View>
        </PanGestureHandler>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: No, didn't found a solution

Comment: It's a known issue. There are multiple tickets about it, the main one https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/139

Answer (score 12):

You can use `GestureHandlerRootView`

```
 import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

 <Modal>
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{flex:1}}>
        <myGestureEnabledComponent/>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
</Modal>
```

*If you're using gesture handler in your component library, you may want to wrap your library's code in the GestureHandlerRootView component. This will avoid extra configuration in MainActivity.java for the user.*
[Source](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/#for-library-authors)

[Related issue](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/139#issuecomment-790329701) in react-native-modal

Comment: Does not make a difference.

Comment: Please check the guide and issue link provided, it is a valid fix for others having different configuration.

Comment: Sounds like it is working now on the latest version, I would like to upvote it now, but I get an error saying I can't because the answer needs to be edited, would you mind creating a small edit?

Comment: No problem, I have edited it alrleady.

Comment: Thank you! The crazy part is with new update now it doesn't work on iOS. (it has nothing to do with this question and answer just saying.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quote from the [doc](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/) of `react-native-gesture-handler` about `Modal` and gesture handler together on Android:

```
Usage with modals on Android#
On Android RNGH does not work by default because modals are not located under React Native Root view in native hierarchy. In order to make it workable, components need to be wrapped with gestureHandlerRootHOC (it's no-op on iOS and web).

E.g.

const ExampleWithHoc = gestureHandlerRootHOC(function GestureExample() {
  return (
    <View>
      <DraggableBox />
    </View>
  );
});

export default function Example() {
  return (
    <Modal animationType="slide" transparent={false}>
      <ExampleWithHoc />
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

But I didn't try the code above.

Comment: Do I have to wrap every single component or just modals?